# Magento 2 Grunt - package.json and grunt file

Tags: npm, gruntjs, magento2

I had problem with Grunt installation with Magento 2.

Below are the two issues:

1. After running `npm install` in magento 2 directory

   > `npm install`
   >
   > `npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/package.json'`
   >
   > `npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/package.json'`
   >
   > `npm WARN html No description`
   >
   > `npm WARN html No repository field.`
   >
   > `npm WARN html No README data`
   >
   > `npm WARN html No license field.`
   >
   > `up to date in 0.089s`
2. Checking grunt - `grunt clean:blank`

   > `grunt clean:blank`
   >
   > `A valid Gruntfile could not be found. Please see the getting started guide for more information on how to configure grunt: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a few tutorials I missed these things:

1. Rename these three files in your magento 2 root directory

   - `package.json.sample`  => `package.json`
   - `grunt.js.sample` => `grunt.js`
   - `grunt-config.js.sample` => `grunt-config.js`

I hope this help someone and save time.